# Using R package: "fitdistrplus" which distribution is better fitting my data?

Tags: r, distributions, bayesian, fitting

I have used "fitdistrplus" to find the possible theoretical distributions that might approximately fit my data.

But am wondering what is the principled way to assess the produced plot (***see pic below the code***) to find out which theoretical distribution might make a better fit?

## Here is my R code:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

n.subjcts = 1e4
scores = numeric(n.subjcts)
set.seed(0)
for(i in 1:n.subjcts){
n.required = sample(0:9, 1, replace = TRUE)
n.correct = sample(0:n.required, 1, replace = TRUE)
n.oversupplied = sample(0:n.correct, 1, replace = TRUE)
scores[i] = n.corrected / sum(n.required, n.oversupplied) 
}

scores = replace(scores, is.infinite(scores), 0) # Removing `Inf` from data

descdist(scores, boot = 1e3)    # checks fit of possible distributions to the data
```

[image]

Comment: Based on the Cullen Frey plot, the Beta distribution may be a good choice. Is your data bounded? Perhaps a histogram of the data would help here.

Comment: @BigAgnes, Well, my data comes from the following formula:  `n.corrected / (n.required + n.oversupplied)`, so basically this gives a continuous range between 0 and 1? BUT, if you run my R code above I get some `Inf`, can I avoid getting such `Inf`?

Comment: Are the variables "n.corrected", "n.required" etc*counts*?? If so, looking at a diagram showing points, lines and regions for *continuous* variables *makes no sense whatever*; the ratio will be discrete. If there's some connection between the variable in the numerator and the two in the denominator you should explain what that is

Comment: @Glen_b, the formula from which scores result produces a continuous range between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Glen_b, did that make sense? The data are obtained via  division of some counts: `n.corrected / sum(n.required, n.oversupplied)`, producing proportions.

Comment: so n.corrected is no more than the sum of the other two ... but how is it connected to them? are these "corrected" values some proportion of the first term in the denominator plus some  different proportion of the second?

Comment: @Glen_b, let me give a bit of theoretical background. Suppose I ask someone to write a few sentences in English in 20 minutes. The goal is to measure that person's knowledge about  the use of **"The"** in English. Now we go to score his writing. We **(a)** count how many "The" were really required (`n.required`) in his writing, **(b)**  how many "The" were correctly used (`n.correct`), and **(c)** how many "The" were used in places where "The" was not needed (`n.oversupplied`). Now put together: $\frac{n.correct}{n.required~+~n.oversupplied}$ .

Comment: 1. Isn't the number correct no larger than the number required?  (i.e. n.correct/n.required would already be between 0 and 1). 2.Note that "correct" and "corrected" mean very different things!  You should not substitute one for the other. ...  From the look of it a binomial might not be an ideal description -- if I did it right from your plot I think the kurtosis might be a bit too high for a binomial of that skewness (but it's probably a good starting point); it's probably the case that n.correct/n.required wuold behave like a binomial though

Comment: @Glen_b, 1. yes, number correct can't be larger than required. 2. thank fixed it.

Comment: @Glen_b, I'm just realizing every measure in my field is like a problem child when I try to understand it statistically!! But, let me ask you something about this formula (i.e., $\frac{n.correct}{n.required~+~n.oversupplied}$ ) which produces proportion type scores. As a professional, if somebody brings you two sets of such scores (produced using that formula) asking you: **"what statistical test** should I use to reveal the difference between these two sets of score",  what would you recommend?

Comment: Are those really proportion type scores? It's like $A/(A+\bar{A}+B)$. The number the subject has supplied has two components (n.correct and n oversupplied  - $A \& B$). There's perhaps some sense in calculating n.oversupplied/n.supplied (*that* is a proportion -- the proportion of "the's" supplied that are not correct, though you could maybe calculate n.correct/n.supplied instead). There's certainly some sense in the ratio "n.correct/n.required" (that is also  a proportion, the proportion of required the's correctly supplied). But n.correct/(n.required+n.oversupplied) will be ... ctd

Comment: ctd... unlikely to be amenable to simple models, since there's no necessary connection between n.correct and n.oversupplied (they won't even be independent). If someone came ot me with data like that I'd start by saying "You're coming to me at the wrong time -- you don't bring data, bring hypotheses and some questions about how to run a study, and then you'll know what to do with the data". If you start by bringing me data, you collected it before choosing your analysis, so you've already spent some researcher degrees of freedom  (maybe a lot for all I know) looking at the data... ctd

Comment: ctd...  Tests won't have the advertised properties. But even if we acted as if you didn't have a period of playing with your data, there's still no clear hypothesis here, so advice about ways to test unspecified hypotheses would be premature. (Hypotheses are not statements about *data*);

Comment: @Glen_b, thank you so much. What I described to you was all past studies done in my field. I am trying to simulate them and make recommendations. Your thoughts were really helpful in this regard.